# AttributeError: expanding_mean doesnt work

Tags: python, pandas

```
samples = {}
n = 30  
num_samples = 500  
for i in range(num_samples):
    samples[i] = population.sample(n).reset_index(drop=True)

samples = pd.DataFrame(samples)

df = pd.DataFrame({'estimated mean': pd.expanding_mean(samples.mean()),
                   'actual population mean': pd.Series(population.mean(), index=samples.columns)})
df.plot(ylim=(4.5, 6.5))
```

hi, this codes give AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'expanding_mean'  What is the correct usage? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `expanding_mean` function was deprecated and removed in newer versions of Pandas. You can achieve the same functionality using `expanding().mean()`.

```
import pandas as pd

samples = {}
n = 30  
num_samples = 500  
for i in range(num_samples):
    samples[i] = population.sample(n).reset_index(drop=True)

samples = pd.DataFrame(samples)

df = pd.DataFrame({'estimated mean': samples.expanding().mean().mean(axis=1),
                   'actual population mean': pd.Series(population.mean(), index=samples.columns)})
df.plot(ylim=(4.5, 6.5))
```

Comment: thank you so muchhh, can you explain what is the n and num_samples pleasee

Comment: n and num_samples are variables used as per your question :

n: This variable represents the sample size. It indicates the number of observations or data points that will be included in each sample. 
num_samples: This variable represents the number of samples to be drawn from the population. It determines how many times the sampling process will be repeated to generate multiple samples.